# How can I run multiple tasks sequentially without blocking the UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to run these tasks sequentially without any blocking in the UI , however, I've test all methods that I've found but I'm still have a problem , when I get tasks runs without UI block I get a missed steps in the tasks or an infinite running of some tasks .

```
 public void StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string path, int i)
    
    {
        var task1 = Task.Run(() => Task1(path, step, i)); // 
        var task2 = Task.Run(() => Task2(cancellationToken)); // wait for task1 to complete
        var task3 = Task.Run(() => Task3(cancellationToken)); // wait for task2 to complete
        var task4 = Task.Run(() => Task4(cancellationToken, i)); // will call an external process ) ... wait for task3 to complete
        Task.WaitAll(task1, task2, task3, task4);
    }

 public void AnotherTask()
    
    {
        // Some other code ( will call an external process )
    }


 public void RunAllTasks()
    {
       int step = 5;
       cancellationToken = CancellationToken.None;
       string path = "...\\..";
       for (int i = 0;i<step;i++)
        {
             StartAsync(cancellationToken, string path, int i) 
        }

      // wait for StartAsync to complete
       AnotherTask();
    }

private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
        RunAllTasks();
    }
```

Comment: Do not use Task.WaitAll. Just call `await Task.Run(...)` four times. Make sure to declare the calling method as `async Task` and await it. The only async void methods may be event handlers.

Comment: [Asynchronous programming in C# with WPF](https://igorpopov.io/2018/06/16/asynchronous-programming-in-csharp-with-wpf/)

Comment: @RobertHarvey , what you have mentioned will blocks the UI

Comment: How can I achieve this ? @Clemens

Comment: @JuniorDev13: Do you mean the blog post?  Unblocking the UI is the only reason one would need asynchronous programming in WPF.  Do you mean adding `async` to a method?  You can't use `await` without declaring the method `async`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey , and what about running tasks sequentially ?

Comment: See Clemens' answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should await each Task like

```
public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string path, int i)    
{
    await Task.Run(() => Task1(path, step, i)); 
    await Task.Run(() => Task2(cancellationToken));
    await Task.Run(() => Task3(cancellationToken));
    await Task.Run(() => Task4(cancellationToken, i));
}
```

or perhaps just call them sequentially in a single Task.Run action, like

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, string path, int i)    
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Task1(path, step, i); 
        Task2(cancellationToken);
        Task3(cancellationToken));
        Task4(cancellationToken, i);
    });
}
```

and await the StartAsync call like

```
public async Task RunAllTasks()
{
     ...
     for (int i = 0;i < step; i++)
     {
         await StartAsync(cancellationToken, path, i);
     }
     ...
}

private async void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{
    await RunAllTasks();
}
```

In case you want to call StartAsync multiple times in parallel, something like this may also work:

```
await Task.WhenAll(Enumerable
    .Range(0, 5)
    .Select(i => StartAsync(cancellationToken, path, i)));
```

Comment: This works because each `await` frees up the UI thread to update the UI, instead of blocking it.

Comment: Are those `await Task.Run(() =>` really needed for those `Task1, Task2.....`? As far as I can see those are not async therefore using one `Task.Run` and putting the loop inside should free up the UIThread and perform all functions sequentially.

Comment: What about `AnotherTask();` ?       `// wait for StartAsync to complete`

Comment: @JuniorDev13 Yes, what about that? We do not know what it is. If it is a synchronous method, just call it after the loop.

Comment: @burnsi You have to ask OP. There is however no loop. It may well be possible to simply call the Task1-4 methods sequentially in a single Run action.

Comment: @Clemens , I've mentionned that should be wait for `StartAsync` to complete , what can I do with it ? , ( however , this task will block the UI , how can I make it run asynch , is it needed also to use Task.Run()` )

Comment: @JuniorDev13 Which Task will block the UI? Please be more clear. Perhaps edit your question.

Comment: The second principal task `AnotherTask();` that will call an external process

Comment: @JuniorDev13 If you can't make the method itself async, do the usual: `await Task.Run(() => AnotherTask());`

Comment: @JuniorDev13 edit your question and add the actual code behind each method. Explain what you actually want to accomplish. You may not need `Task.Run` for IO tasks, as most IO classes have async methods. Calling an external process - what does that mean? Starting another process and waiting for it? Or talking to a service through ... something? You can await a child process to exit with `WaitForExitAsync`. Or are you trying to use Office Automation to eg drive Excel? You can probably get rid of Excel entirely with the correct library, eg Epplus to generate Excel, ExcelDataReader to read it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , No I'm calling an external process ( executable application that doing calculation ) , what's not cleared in my question to edit it?

Comment: @JuniorDev13 "calling an external process" means nothing. Calling how? Writing to its standard input stream? Some other inter-process mechanism like pipes or the clipboard? Using TCP? Using COM? HTTP? Memory mapped files? Some client library? Many of these mechanism can run asynchronously. Some can't

Comment: No it's no related to TCP or COM or HTTP , it's an exe app for complexe calculation

Comment: @JuniorDev13 If your next problem is how to wrap the invokation of an external application in an awaitable method, that is completely out of the scope of *this* question.  A possible solution would involve the Process class and its event handlers, and perhaps the TaskCompletionSource class. Try to search these things on the internet, and eventually come back with another, more specific question.

Comment: @JuniorDev13 which means you're writing to its input stream? Streams have asynchronous methods too.  `No it's no related` isn't a useful answer. Not if you want to get rid of all blocking code anyway

Comment: @Clemens, Unfortantly , I've test your solution and seems not works for me , I don't why maybe your solution will works in some cases or only for another problems not mine , I'm still getting uncompleted tasks and uncompleted results ( output of tasks )

Comment: @Clemens , Your solution seems not works for me , I've test it and I'm still getting an uncompleted tasks , this is due to no await from tasks , what I mean is that task2 will run before task1 complete the execution ...

Comment: @JuniorDev13 Your Task1-4 methods may be broken. Perhaps they start themselves an async action without awaiting it, we don't know. The fact that you have wrapped them in Task.Run calls should however indicate that they are ordinary (long running) methods.

Comment: Not broken , I think that some tasks have a code that connect to the UI , I'm getting an exception `Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException'` and this exception seems to be `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it` , however, I'm not using `Try-Catch` block , the code that is used to connect to the UI is about increment a progress bar

Comment: @JuniorDev13 You have to use the Dispatcher of the UI thread to access UI elements from a thread other than the UI thread. Just search for the error message, there are hundreds of such question here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @JuniorDev13 post a question asking about your actual requirement. Right now you're asking about what you think the solution would look like, confusing yourself and everyone else. Why pause anything instead of awaiting for some operation to complete asynchronously? If you want to ask user confirmation in the middle of an async method, go ahead - `await` returns execution to the UI thread. You can use `TaskCompletionSource` to create something that allows awaiting events. Assume the people answering you have already encountered and solved the same high-level problems before